# Create a series of point button based on number of div

Tags: php, html, css

I want create a list of button, for example a number X mini-balls, based on a number X of divs into a container. I want this:

∞ ∞ ∞ ∞

based on a number of divs.

and each of this button has a position of each div (with animation scroller) and if I click one of items I'll go to this position linked to div.

For example:

```
<div id="scroller">
<div id="content">number1</div>
<div id="content">number2</div>
<div id="content">number3</div>
</div>
```

And I've:

```
<ul>
<li><div id="ball"></div></li>
<li><div id="ball"></div></li>
<li><div id="ball"></div></li>
</ul>
```

So if I click on third "mini-ball", I'll go to position of div "number3".

I hope that you understand!

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot give same Ids to different elements!!**

basically you need to show a specific division upon click of a specific button. There are many ways to go about this.

All of these many methods, would require you to do one thing, **detect the particular button click and deduce the div to be shown**

Below am showing you world's simplest sample (for the sake of it)..it should give you an idea:

respective html:

```
<body >
     <ul>
        <li><div id="ball1" data-target="content1">button 1</div></li>
        <li><div id="ball2" data-target="content2">button 2</div></li>
        <li><div id="ball3" data-target="content3">button 3</div></li>
    </ul>   

   <div id="scroller">
        <div id="content1" class="number">number1</div>
        <div id="content2" class="number">number2</div>
        <div id="content3" class="number">number3</div>
    </div>


</body>
```

respective jquery code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function(){

       $('ul').find('li').find('div').click(function(){

             var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
             $('#'+target).slideToggle(1000);

       });

    });
</script>
```

respective style:

```
<style>
    .number
    {
       display:none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: i don't understand...so have i to create a jquery that count automatically the divs id content? how? can i edit the class for number? thanks for reply..

Comment: no. you have to create your html structure that way. you have to give them Id manually. you can do this by statically typing or dynamically appending through jquery/javascript. and later you can process your html structure like this. you can find any element in the page using jquery and process it accordingly